# BigCommerce Back button needed

Tags: button, navigation, bigcommerce, back

Is there some way that we can possibly incorporate/code a simple old style universal 'Back' button on all our product pages?

BigCommerce only allows for a standard breadcrumbs trail below the main menu that is not intuitive or user friendly for many visitors.

A visitor will either use our main PARTS menu page or the search function to check out many individual parts and then want to go straight back to the PARTS menu or at least the last 'group' results from their search and an obvious and plain old 'Back' button right next to the part would be an asset.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you add something similar to the below example to your product page template (wherever you want to add it), you can achieve it.

```
<button onclick="window.back.history(-1);"> Back Button </button>
```

It's inline javascript, which is not the best way to do it, but it will work. For more, you will need to add custom js file and do everything there.